# WPF - Access DependencyObject inside a CollectionChanged event

Tags: wpf, observablecollection, dependency-properties

I have an user control that combines the values of 2 DepedenciyProperties:

**int numberPeople** and **ingredients Lists<>**

I want when either of these values updates to redo the combination.
My current implementation uses a static variable to keep track of the object instance (objectInstance). I am wondering if there is a cleaner way to do this.

```
private static DependencyObject objectInstance;

    public int numberPeople
    {
        get { return (int)GetValue(numberPeopleProperty); }
        set { SetValue(numberPeopleProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty numberPeopleProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("numberPeople", typeof(int), typeof(ListDisplayer), new PropertyMetadata(0, Combine));


    public ObservableCollection<ListModel> ingredients
    {
        get { return (ObservableCollection<ListModel>)GetValue(ingredientsProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ingredientsProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ingredientsProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("ingredients", typeof(ObservableCollection<ListModel>), typeof(ListDisplayer), new PropertyMetadata(null, AssignCollectionChangedToList));
    private static void AssignCollectionChangedToList(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var instance = d as ListDisplayer;
        if (e.OldValue != null)
        {
            var coll = (INotifyCollectionChanged)e.OldValue;
            coll.CollectionChanged -= ItemsSource_CollectionChanged;
        }

        if (e.NewValue != null)
        {
            instance.ItemsSource = (ObservableCollection<ListModel>)e.NewValue;
            objectInstance = instance;
            instance.ItemsSource.CollectionChanged += ItemsSource_CollectionChanged;
        }
    }

    private static void ItemsSource_CollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        // MY PROBLEM: when a new item is added in this list trigger again Combine(), is there 
        // another way to trigger the Combine so that it will process the IngredientList and numberPeople attached to the object ? 
        Combine(objectInstance, new DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs());

    }




    private static void Combine(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        // process numberPeople and ingredientList
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit:** Remove the `static` keyword from the definition of the `ItemsSource_CollectionChanged` event handler and hook it up using the "instance" reference:

```
private static void AssignCollectionChangedToList(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var instance = d as ListDisplayer;
    if (e.OldValue != null)
    {
        var coll = (INotifyCollectionChanged)e.OldValue;
        coll.CollectionChanged -= instance.ItemsSource_CollectionChanged;
    }

    if (e.NewValue != null)
    {
        instance.ingredients = (ObservableCollection<ListModel>)e.NewValue;
        objectInstance = instance;
        instance.ingredients.CollectionChanged += instance.ItemsSource_CollectionChanged;
    }
}

private void ItemsSource_CollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    Combine(this, new DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs());
}
```

Also the CLR wrappers of your dependency properties are not correctly implemented. You should pass the dependency property to the GetValue and SetValue methods:

```
public int numberPeople
{
    get { return (int)GetValue(numberPeopleProperty); }
    set { SetValue(numberPeopleProperty, value); }
}
public static readonly DependencyProperty numberPeopleProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("numberPeople", typeof(int), typeof(ListDisplayer), new PropertyMetadata(0, Combine));


public ObservableCollection<ListModel> ingredients
{
    get { return (ObservableCollection<ListModel>)GetValue(ingredientsProperty); }
    set { SetValue(ingredientsProperty, value); }
}
public static readonly DependencyProperty ingredientsProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("ingredients", typeof(ObservableCollection<ListModel>), typeof(ListDisplayer), new PropertyMetadata(null, AssignCollectionChangedToList));
```

Comment: updated the code and the comments with my question from the code. The comments are now inside the method ItemsSource_CollectionChanged. Hope I have managed to explain well what my question is this time.